# Getting Intermittent "Socket exceptions" when trying to connect the Azure Service bus via Azure Timer function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-app-service-plans, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus nuget package to connect to Azure service bus (pricing tier: standard) via Azure timer trigger function (function triggers in every 2 min). The function is running on a App Plan (Standard S2 1 Instance). The function app is throwing intermittent socket exceptions whenever it tries to connect to service bus. Below is the stack trace:-

I am using ManagementClient class to get the active message count from the service bus subscription queue using GetSubscriptionRuntimeInfoAsync() method. If the message count is greater than 0 then process the message else avoid. Any suggestions why I am getting the below error:-

**Update 1:** ManagementClient class is part of Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus nuget package. And while creating the ManagementClient instance I am passing the sevice bus connectionstring, and i am getting sockets exceptions here with InnerException message as "Not such host known" or sometimes "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

```
var managementClient = await _myhelper.GetManagementClient();//returning new instance of managementclient
try
{
    var runTimeInfo = await managementClient.GetSubscriptionRuntimeInfoAsync("MyTopicName", "MySubscriptionName");
    if (runTimeInfo != null && runTimeInfo.MessageCountDetails.ActiveMessageCount > 0)
    {
        //Do message processing
    }
    else
    {
        //No messages in queue. Hence, return
    }
}
finally
{
    await managementClient.CloseAsync();
}

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__20.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version= 3.0.29.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:326)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsync>d__15.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version= 3.0.29.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:94)
Inner exception Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient+<SendHttpRequest>d__53.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version= 4.2.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient+<GetEntity>d__50.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version= 4.2.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient+<GetSubscriptionRuntimeInfoAsync>d__20.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version= 4.2.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at +<GetSubscriptionRuntimeInfo>d__6.MoveNext (, Version= 1.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= null: D:\a\1\s\Helper.cs:73)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at d__10.MoveNext ( Version= 1.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= null: D:\a\1\s\Helper.cs:61)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at <Run>d__4.MoveNext ( Version= 1.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= null: D:\a\1\s\myclass.cs:57)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__2.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version= 3.0.29.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\VoidTaskMethodInvoker.cs:20)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version= 3.0.29.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:52)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeWithTimeoutAsync>d__27.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version= 3.0.29.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:555)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version= 3.0.29.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:501)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__20.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version= 3.0.29.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:279)
Inner exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException handled at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient+<SendHttpRequest>d__53.MoveNext:
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<ConnectAsync>d__1.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version= 4.2.2.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<ConnectAsync>d__52.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version= 4.2.2.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync>d__53.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version= 4.2.2.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<GetHttpConnectionAsync>d__45.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version= 4.2.2.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at **System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool**+<SendWithRetryAsync>d__47.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version= 4.2.2.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version= 4.2.2.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version= 4.2.2.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__70.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version= 4.2.2.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient+<SendHttpRequest>d__53.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version= 4.2.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
Inner exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException handled at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<ConnectAsync>d__1.MoveNext:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Private.CoreLib, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<ConnectAsync>d__1.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version= 4.2.2.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
```

Comment: Could you share the helper code and elaborate what are trying to achieve to avoid guessing?

Comment: @SeanFeldman: I 've updated my question details, there is nothing as such in the helper code to share, I am just returning new instance of ManagementClient in my helper class i.e. // return new ManagementClient(MyServicebusConnectionstring);. I am trying to get the active message count from the service bus subscription queue and if the count is greater than 0 then I am processing the messages else return. Please let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: opening a connection to the service bus is not a cheap operation. It would be better to follow the recommendation and keep it cached, especially since your function is triggered every 2 minutes and the same instance is re-used. That at least will reduce the chances of having a connectivity error as there will be fewer attempts. You'll find the necessary info [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections). Saying that you shouldn't be getting that many errors. Unless you have too many (>5000) connections to your namespace. Try and let me know if it works.